# How to persist Vue 3 store without Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I'm using the `vue 3 store` to pass around values between components, in this case an image link.

**`store.js`**:

```
import {reactive} from "vue";

const re = reactive({})

export default {
    re
}
```

An image link is assigned in a component:

```
store.re.article = '../../images/1.jpg'
```

and recalled in another component:

```
<img :src="store.re.article">
```

Problem now is that the store is not persistent. When I refresh the page, the image does not get loaded because the link does not exist anymore. I could use `localstorage`/`sessionstorage` but was wondering if there is a more elegant way of achieving persistant store (like in `vuex` for example).

Comment: As long as you don't store anything related to security, I don't think the usage of local/session storage is not elegant. People nowadays (generally speaking) think browser storage is not elegant, but they don't feel enraged by the rise of so many useless libraries based on js, which can be replaced so easily by simpler/vanilla solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This tool existed, but it's not maintained anymore. https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate

I think you'll be fine using Session or Localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

for those who use pinia there is a very recent solution being worked on:

https://github.com/prazdevs/pinia-plugin-persistedstate